# Fixed position header bar issue

Tags: html, css

I tried to implement fixed position header bar. But when I try to resize window to smaller width, right part of header is not shown.. If I changed position to absolute, problem is resolved but I'm losing the fixed effect of header bar..

```
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
display: block;
height:56px;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 0px;
background-color: #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index: 99999;
}
```

here is the html;

```
<body>
  <div id="mask"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="center">
            <a id="logoWrapper" href="/makale"><div id="logo"></div></a>
            <div id="categoryWrapper">

                <ul>
                   <li>...</li>
                   <li>...</li>
                 </ul>

            </div>
            <div id="searchWrapper">
                <div id="search">
                    <input type="text" />
                    <a id="searchBt" href="#"><img src="/images/site/search.png"></a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Here is the link http://sporapp.com/makale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem some time ago. look at my older post up there -> [Make Fixed Header Scroll Horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785598/css-make-fixed-header-scroll-horizontal)

you can use jQuery or Javascript to reposition the div on the top of the page ( causes some laggy effect sometimes )

Comment: yeap it's a solution but hope it can fixed through css not javascript as you told it has laggy effect

Comment: yeah. in that case whats about making a fixed width of the header div ?? it seems to me that the div is not scrolling horizontally with the page because it always fits the width so no overflow is happening...

Comment: or just set a min-width:900px or something like that

Comment: can you post the html code ? maybe you can trick with the arrangement of the div's

Comment: ok I posted the html, also you can see with the link i shared on live.

Comment: did you tryed to put the "content" div inside the "wrapper" div ? so all the content will be traced as one object and maybe if you scroll horizontal the header will scroll with the page content. you maybe wan't to give the wrapper div a css style like overflow:wisible and a fixed width

Comment: content div already in wrapper div.. i tried overflow:visible for wrapper div, didn't work either.

Comment: oh i see now... hmm, thats a really hard nut. i was trying exactly this just withj css and html. but i think you should ude javascript or even jQuerry for better performance ( i dont tested it )

Comment: thanks @Ace, I think I'll drop the requirement.. I checked the twitter header bar which is fixed and has the same problem.. as an entrepreneur if they dont care with lots of user then it's pointless to spend hours and hours on this problem, anyway thank you man :)

Comment: you're welcome. mark as answer for other people who are searching for the same problem. and i also think that for a less comercial website ( something that dont have thousands and millions of users a day ) nobody should spend that much time for little things. the most important thing is that the whole site is working correct and it looks nice. and i think everybody is able to scroll up the page again to use the header menu ^^ have a nice day

Comment: I dropped the problem actually, fixed header staying :)

Comment: well, then you should keep in mind that the header div should be smaller or qeual to width:1000px to make shure al propper screen resolutions will show all the content in full-sized-window at least.

Answer (score 0):

hie, i have fixed your problem. You must have to add `min-width` property of css for `#header` portion while working on resizing window.

`CSS:`

```
#wrapper
{
background-color: #F4F4F4;
display: block;
height: auto;
min-height:100%;
min-width:980px;
overflow:auto;
width: 100%;
}

#header 
{
backgroung-color: #333333;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: block;
height: 56px;
min-width: 1265px; // Here, if you want to adjust your min-width of header as per your need (for that you can use fire bug) else remains same
padding-left:0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 99999;
}

#header #center
{
margin: 0 auto;
width:980px;
}
```

Hope, it will helps you. Cheers. !! 
Mark it as answer if it will helps you so that other can fix their same problem. Thanks. !!

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem is if i changed to position to absolute from fixed, everything is ok.. i didnt see any relation in your answer

Comment: I inserted the link in the question.. just use chrome developers or firebug, you can easly see all html and css

Comment: see my edit, i have fix your problem and dn't forget to mark it as answer if it works for you. cheers. !!

Comment: I tried what you said in your answer but absolute positioning on header is not the solution i want, it should be fixed

Comment: i have tried and its working properly from my side. i have also tested with Fire bug.

Comment: I know problem is solved when we changed the position to absolute, see my question, I already said when i asked.. But if position is absolute then the header is not sticking to anymore and i dont want it.. wherever i scroll i want the header is shown.. so the solution you came with need to solve the problem and provide the requirements